# How to initialize a pandas dataframe with empty lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to achieve the following as an example:

| ix | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [] | [] |
| 1 | [] | [] |

Comment: I want to achieve it with this `entity_textitem_matrix = pd.DataFrame([], index=basket_sets.columns, columns=basket_sets.columns)`

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh nope as it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), you can make a dataframe by passing a dictionary in the shape {'Column' : ['values']}. In this case:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [[], []], 'B': [[], []]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df)
#    A   B
# 0  []  []
# 1  []  []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically, you could use:

```
idx  = [0,1]
cols = ['A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame([[[] for i in range(len(cols))] for i in range(len(idx))],
                  index=idx, columns=cols,
                 )
```

output:

```
    A   B
0  []  []
1  []  []
```

Or you could cheat a bit and take advantage of pandas `str` methods:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame('', index=idx, columns=cols)
        .apply(lambda c: c.str.split())
     )
```

output:

```
    A   B
0  []  []
1  []  []
```